# TabListener constructor in FragmentTabs.java

Tags: android, constructor, fragment, android-actionbar

In the Android API example [FragmentTabs.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.html) I see the following constructor code inside the TabListener class:

```
        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
        if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(mFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

Can someone please give me a hint under which circumstances the if clause can return true? I cannot think of such a situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you turn your phone from Portrait to Landscape or back.

The current active tab will not be detached.

I just tested it by putting a breakpoint in that clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! On the other hand I thought that when I turn the device the complete activity with its fragments are destroyed and then rebuilt. How can it be that a fragment is still existing after a configuration change?

Comment: It seems that the system automatically destroys but then re-creates all fragments when the activity is re-created. But I am still not really sure that the extra code is needed and correct...